# Parsing CEF files in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

We have staged the log files in external stage s3.The staged log files are in CEF file format.How to parse CEF files from stage to move the data to snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

If the files have a fixed format (i.e. there are record and field delimiters and each record has the same number of columns) then you can just treat it as a text file and create an appropriate file format.

If the file has a semi-structured format then you should be able to load it into a variant column - whether you can create multiple rows per file or only one depends in the file structure. If you can only create one record per file then you may run into issues with file size as a variant column has a maximum file size.

Once the data is in a variant column you should be able to process it to extract usable data from it. If there is a structure Snowflake can process (e.g. xml or json) then you can use the native capabilities. If there is no recognisable structure then you'd have to write your own parsing logic in a stored procedure.

Alternatively, you could try and find another tool that will convert your files to an xml/json format and then Snowflake can easily process those files.